# Is it possible to specify in a POM a specific JDK to run a given maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have been asked to provide for signing a jar using specific JDK 1.8 whereas project is being 1.7 compliant.
How can I achieve this, assuming it is feasable?
I have a default JDK 1.8 with which a jenkins job would execute a maven job

The **application is 1.7** coded so in its pom.xml there is the following configuration:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>           
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>.....</version>
        <configuration>
             .....
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
            .....
        </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

As they need to sign the jar, and **they have been recommended to use jarsigner of 1.8**, I wonder how can I force
maven-jarsigner-plugin ....

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>...</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>sign</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>sign</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
      <keystore>${keystore.file}</keystore>
      <alias>${keystore.alias}</alias>
      <storepass>${keystore.password}</storepass>
      <storetype>${keystore.type}</storetype>
      <sigfile>XXX</sigfile>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

... **to use JDK8**
Is that feasable?
How?

many thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 0):

Just configure only JDK8 for this.

The `maven-compiler-plugin` will assure you to compile Java 1.7 compliant code.

On the other hand the `maven-jarsigner-plugin` will transparentely sign the jars using the JDK8.

Just to be clear `jarsigner` is a JDK utility, it's impossible to run `jarsigner` of JDK 1.8 in a older (say 1.7) version way.

Comment: Sorry for the delay

Comment: Assuming I configure jenkins job to use JDK 1.8, how can I be certain that the jar signer behind the scene is really picked from JDK1.8? Are we sure that jenkins'maven plugin as well as all maven plugins mentioned in pom are going to use jdk1.8?

Comment: It depends entirely on how is configured the JDK in your jenkins'maven plugin. And, just to understand, how many JDK do you have in your jenkins/maven configuration?

Comment: The plugins `maven-compiler-plugin` and `maven-jarsigner-plugin` are executed almost sequentially during the execution of the same maven goal?

Comment: and again, it's impossible to run `jarsigner` of JDK 1.8 in a older (say 1.7) version way. All you have to do is use only the JDK 1.8

Comment: sorry I am newbie at stackoverflow, I would need to post the pom , yet I can't see a straightforward way to do it, as It would be hard to format it. I am just reading the pom and this is not what I would expect to be and it is a very complex one. How can I post/attach it here?

Comment: when you say: "ll you have to do is use only the JDK 1.8" can you tell me if it is enough to set the maven jenkins job to use it or is it a POM setting?

Comment: Usually there is only one JDK configured in Jenkins.  So it's easier than you think, all you have to do is just run the pom.xml. If you want be really sure just check that jenkins is using the JDK 1.8 for the maven jobs.

Comment: Thanks for helping: To answer to you question I have more than one node and per each node I have 3 jdk configured (1.6, 1.7, 1.8). The job is configured to run with 1.7 still I can set it to run with jdk 1.8 though what I need to be sure of is: is it enough to congifure the job to be jdk1.8 to be sure its maven plugin and all the goals mentioned in pom (among which jar-signer) be run with jdk1.8?

Comment: Ok, I understand. Anyway, once you have configured the job to run with the right jdk (1.8) everything should go fine. May be you already know that you can specify the target (1.7) while compiling with the 1.8 JDK, and this is what the `maven-compiler-plugin` does in your case.  `maven-compiler-plugin` just specify `-target` and `-source` during compile step.

Comment: Thanks Freedev for helping :-)

Comment: And given you're a SO newbie read the Jeff Atwood (SO founder) answer  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/why-should-i-upvote-a-question

Comment: Thank you Freedev. So far I can't have any feedback as long as I am not authorized to change the pom (I am just the one supposed to give assistance in this), I would like to put verbose=true in the maven-jarsigner-plugin though I am not sure this is going to display the current jdk being used by the plugin. As soon as I have news I will update this and, in case, I would be glad to mark it solved. I am going to read the article you suggested. (at least in order to be able to give a decent format to my statements).

Comment: In jenkins'node we can have, as we have, more than one JDK available. 
I eventually configured and run jenkins job either with jdk1.7 or jdk1.8
By adding verbose=true to maven-jarsigner-plugin I obtain what follows in job's console output:
JDK7:
[debug] jarsigner executable=[/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.17.x86_64/jre/../bin/jarsigner]
JDK8:
[debug] jarsigner executable=[/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/jre/../bin/jarsigner]

Comment: So definitely, I would state: 
once we set JDK to run a jenkin's maven project (aka job) that jdk is the one used by jenkin's maven plugin in order to execute each of the plugins mentioned in pom.
Freedev I have voted yours as the best answer : :-)
Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Thanks Francesco. BTW still I don't see the answer marked as correct or any up vote. Are you sure you did it?

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that, when I vote, I received the following message. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the desired JDK 8 is the only JDK in the compile classpath.
2. In the POM, set the backward source and target version information (your example shows that you are already doing this).
3. Add the maven-jarsigner-plugin to the POM.
4. Configure the desired JDK 8 jar signer.

Comment: we can have, as we have, several JDK available.

Comment: that is a waste of time.  Just simplify the environment and use one JDK.  There is no value gained by using multiple JDK installations for the problem you described.